# Keycloak custom event listener not deploying

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, keycloak

I'm trying to create a custom event listener and faced a problem that while I running the container with keycloak there is not any logging info about deploying of mine .jar file of a project.

My sequence of actions before running the container with keycloak:

mvn clean package -> build -t custom-keycloak . -> docker-compose up

Besides implementations bellow I have a file *org.keycloak.events.EventListenerProviderFactory* that contains directory of mine implementation of event listener provider factory - *SimpleEventListenerProvider*.

**Event listener provider implementation**

```
@Component
public class SimpleEventListenerProvider implements EventListenerProvider {

    @Override
    public void onEvent(Event event) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(AdminEvent adminEvent, boolean b) {
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {

    }
}
```

**Event listener provider factory implementation**

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SimpleEventListenerProviderFactory implements EventListenerProviderFactory {
    private final SimpleEventListenerProvider provider;

    @Override
    public EventListenerProvider create(KeycloakSession keycloakSession) {
        return provider;
    }

    @Override
    public void init(Config.Scope scope) {

    }

    @Override
    public void postInit(KeycloakSessionFactory keycloakSessionFactory) {

    }

    @Override
    public void close() {

    }

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return "session-restrictor";
    }
}
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:19.0.0

ARG APPLICATION_JAR=target/*.jar

COPY ${APPLICATION_JAR} /opt/keycloak/providers

RUN /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh build  show-config --metrics-enabled=true
```

**Docker compose**

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - /home/lib/v1:/var/lib/v1
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USERNAME: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: data

  keycloak:
    container_name: keycloak
    image: custom-keycloak:latest
    volumes:
      - /home/lib/keycloak/v1:/var/lib/keycloak/v1
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
      KEYCLOAK_MANAGEMENT_PASSWORD: admin
      KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_PORT: 5432
      KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_HOST: postgres
      KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_NAME: data
      KEYCLOAK_CREATE_ADMIN_USER: 'true'
      KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_USER: postgres
      KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_PASSWORD: postgres
    entrypoint: ["/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh", "start-dev", "--features=preview"]
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_started
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced the same issue, unfortunately the documentation on [configuring providers](https://www.keycloak.org/server/configuration-provider) is very sparse and does not mention the **important** notice that the `src/resources/META-INF` folder must contain a text file with your `SimpleEventListenerProviderFactory`.

The solution would be to create the folder `src/resources/META-INF/` and place a plain text file as follows.

`org.keycloak.events.EventListenerProviderFactory`:

```
your.package.name.SimpleEventListenerProviderFactory
```

Don't forget to build the configuration again with `kc.sh build` before running `kc.sh start`

This costed me some hours to figure out. But now it finally shows in the keycloak admin page. Due to lack of better examples, I can only provide [my implementation](https://gitlab.phaidra.org/fair-data-austria-db-repository/fda-services/-/tree/f55f2535d743ad78f38e13963ad5c717788f8681/fda-authentication-service/rabbitmq-event-listener/src/main). Also notice the xml file:

`jboss-deployment-structure.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-services" />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```